Php Laravel 11 Email Verification
By email verification in Laravel 11 user not authenticated or null after verification link clicked and by the email resend link the same error.
web.php
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController as UserDashboardCnt;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController as UserLoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


//   USER

// Guest middleware
Route::group(['middleware' => ['user.guest', 'restrict.admin', 'restrict.company']], function () {
    Route::get('/user/login', [UserLoginController::class, 'index'])->name('user.login');
    Route::get('/user/register', [UserLoginController::class, 'register'])->name('user.register');
    Route::post('/user/process-register', [UserLoginController::class, 'processRegister'])->name('user.processRegister');
    Route::post('/user/authenticate', [UserLoginController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('user.authenticate');

});


// Authenticated middleware (without 'verified')
Route::group(['middleware' => ['user.auth', 'verified']], function () {
    Route::get('/user/logout', [UserLoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('user.logout');
    Route::get('/user/dashboard', [UserDashboardCnt::class, 'index'])->name('user.dashboard');

});


Route::middleware(['user.auth'])->group(function () {
    
    Route::post('/email/verification-notification', [LoginController::class, 'verifyHandler'])
    ->middleware('throttle:6,1')
    ->name('verification.send');
});
Route::get('/email/verify', [LoginController::class, 'verifyNotice'])
    ->name('verification.notice');

Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [LoginController::class, 'verifyEmail'])
    ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
    ->name('verification.verify');
    

loginController.php
I am using Auth::login($user) in processRegister just for the time being its working
bucause if i use the Auth::guard('user') its error. user not authenticated or null!
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; // Import the Hash facade
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    // This page will show login page for customer
    public function index()
    {
        return view('user.login');
    }

    //  This method will authenticate user
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {

        // Define custom messages
        $messages = [
            'email.exists' => 'Invalid credentials.',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|exists:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ], $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return redirect()->route('user.login')
                ->withInput($request->except('password'))
                ->withErrors($validator);
        }

        if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {

            if (Auth::guard('user')->user()->role !== "user") {

                Auth::guard('user')->logout();

                return redirect()->route('user.login')
                    ->withInput($request->except('password'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => 'Unauthorized access!.']);
            }

            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->route('user.login')
            ->withInput($request->except('password'))
            ->withErrors(['email' => 'Invalid credentials.']);
    }


    //  This method will show the user register page
    public function register()
    {
        return view('user.register');
    }


    public function processRegister(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the incoming request data
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);
    
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            // Create and save the new user
            $user = new User();
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
            $user->role = 'user';
            $user->save();
    
            // Trigger the Registered event
            event(new Registered($user));
    
            // Log in the user
            Auth::login($user);
    
            // Log the successful login
            \Log::info('User logged in after registration.', ['user_id' => $user->id]);
    
            // Check if the user is now logged in
            if (Auth::check()) {
                // Redirect to the email verification notice
                return redirect()->route('user.login')
                    ->with('success', 'Successfully Registered. Verify your Email.');
            } else {
                // If for some reason the login failed, log the error and redirect to the register page
                \Log::error('User was not logged in after registration', ['user_id' => $user->id]);
                return redirect()->route('user.register')
                    ->with('error', 'There was an issue logging in after registration. Please try logging in.');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('user.register')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }



    //  Verify Email Notice handler
    public function verifyNotice()
    {

        return view('auth.verify-email');
    }



    //  Email verification handler
    public function verifyEmail(EmailVerificationRequest $request)
    {
        // Log the incoming verification request
        \Log::info('Email verification request received.', [
            'request' => $request->all(),
            'route_id' => $request->route('id'),
        ]);

        // Fulfill the email verification (marks email as verified)
        $request->fulfill();
        \Log::info('Email verification fulfilled for user.', ['email' => $request->user()->email]);

        // Log whether the user is authenticated using the 'user' guard
        \Log::info('Auth::guard(user)->check(): ' . (Auth::guard('user')->check() ? 'Authenticated' : 'Not Authenticated'));


        // Redirect to dashboard or wherever needed
        \Log::info('Redirecting to user dashboard after email verification.', ['user_id' => Auth::guard('user')->id()]);
        return redirect()->route('user.login')->with('success', 'Email verified successfully. Please Login.');
    }

    public function verifyHandler(Request $request)
    {
        // Log whether the user is authenticated using the 'user' guard
        \Log::info('Auth::guard(user)->check(): ' . (Auth::guard('user')->check() ? 'Authenticated' : 'Not Authenticated'));

        // Check if the user is authenticated
        if (!Auth::guard('user')->check()) {
            // Try to retrieve the user from the request
            $user = $request->user();

            // Log if a user was found or not
            \Log::info('Request user: ', ['user' => $user]);

            // Ensure the user exists before logging them in
            if ($user) {
                Auth::guard('user')->login($user);
                \Log::info('User logged in successfully.');
            } else {
                \Log::error('No authenticated user found.');
                return back()->with('error', 'No authenticated user found.');
            }
        }

        // Log that the verification email is being sent
        \Log::info('Sending verification email to user.');

        // Send email verification notification
        $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return back()->with('message', 'Verification link sent!');
    }

    // This method will logout user
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('user')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('user.login');
    }
}

additional snippets
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {

        $middleware->alias([
            'admin.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminRedirect::class,
            'admin.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,
            'restrict.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminRestrictAccess::class,
            'company.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\CompanyRedirect::class,
            'company.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\CompanyAuthenticate::class,
            'restrict.company' => \App\Http\Middleware\CompanyRestrictAccess::class,
            'user.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserRedirect::class,
            'user.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserAuthenticate::class,
            'restrict.user' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserRestrictAccess::class,
            'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

        ]);

        $middleware->redirectTo(
            guests: '/user/login',
            users: '/user/dashboard'
        );
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'user' => [ // New guard for user
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'company' => [ // New guard for companies
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'companies',
        ],

        'admin' => [ // New guard for admin
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
        ],

        'companies' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

Please, anyone out there have an idea?

what is user.auth middleware? why do you need so many guards if they do the same thing??
